# Does setting margin for child element affect the size for parent element?

Tags: html, css

I'm confused as to why sometimes the parent element will sometimes not consider the margin of the child element for its size.

Here is the code:

```css
section::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

section.main {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 0;
}

section.main aside {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33%;
}

section.main .content {
  margin: 15px;
  background: no-repeat center top;
  background-size: 75px 75px;
  padding-top: 85px;
}
```

```html
<section class="main">
  <aside>
    <div class="content trending">
      <h3><a href="#">Where to find it</a></h3>
      <p>Morbi commodo, ipsum sed pharetra gravida, orci magna rhoncus neque, id pulvinar odio lorem non turpis. Nullam sit amet enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect.</p>

    </div>
  </aside>

</section>
```

The body element will not consider the margin of section with a class called main for its height, but the the aside element will for its child, why is this so?

Comment: The body element is considering the margin of section

Comment: section margin seems to fine - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/KeWeKq , i gave background color for reference to see the margin from parent

Comment: if you inspect element and see the body and section, the section margin is outside the body, but its different for the aside and div with class content and trending

Comment: default css of body uses margin:8px;  due to which you see that the section margin is outside body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margins of the child elements can "leak" through the top and bottom edges of the parent element (this is a special case of [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)) if these elements participate in the same [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) and the parent element has no border or padding on that edge (to put it simply). The `section` element is in the same block formatting context as the `body` element and the `body` element has no paddings or borders by default, so this condition is satisfied. The content of the `section` (the `aside` element) is floated, and floats are controlled by a special layout algorithm and don't belong to the block formatting context (and establish new block formatting contexts for their content), so its margins don't collapse with the margins of `section`.

Answer (score 0):

"Margins collapse between adjacent elements. In simple terms, this means that for adjacent vertical block-level elements in the normal document flow, only the margin of the element with the largest margin value will be honored, while the margin of the element with the smaller margin value will be collapsed to zero"